# Is regex enough to stop injection attacks?

Tags: php, regex, sql-injection, code-injection

I have a script that processes user input and before it continues with database interaction it verifies input with regex. My only question is, Is regex enough to weed out injection attacks or do I still need to apply `mysql_real_escape_string()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on how "good" the expression is; as in, "did you cover all your bases?" It doesn't hurt to put it through `mysql_real_escape_string` to be safe. There is no performance impact if you use this a few times in your script.

Answer (score 1):

It is if the regex is `^$`. For all other inputs, it depends on whether the regexp lets escape characters through. Since those depend on the database and connection settings, you should really use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or, if that's not an option, `mysql_real_escape_string` every time.

Answer (score 1):

If your regex is good enough then yes, however, why take the risk?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have an amazing RegEx expression, I personally wouldn't trust it to be complete.

Always error on the side of too much protection rather than too little. Include the call to `mysql_real_escape_string`.